# How do I get a ready function and another function to play nicely in document.ready?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, asset-pipeline

In my `post.js`, I have this:

```
var ready;
ready = function() {

    // This is the Sidebar toggle functionality
    var toggleSidebar = $(".togglesidebar");
    var primary = $("#primary");
    var secondary = $("#secondary");

    toggleSidebar.on("click", function(){

        if(primary.hasClass("col-sm-9")){
            primary.removeClass("col-sm-9");
            primary.addClass("col-sm-12");
            secondary.css('display', 'none');
        }
        else {
            primary.removeClass("col-sm-12");
            primary.addClass("col-sm-9");
            secondary.css('display', 'inline-block');
        }
    }); 
};

$(document).ready(ready);
```

Which works MOST of the time. There are times when the `toggleSidebar` doesn't toggle (e.g. when you go to a different page and come back to the main where the main button is...it doesn't toggle. I have to refresh the page before it starts working again...I suspect this is related to Turbolinks though)...but that's a side issue. That's not the core issue here.

I also have this:

```
counter = function() {
    var body_value = $('#post_body').val();
    var title_value = $('#post_title').val();       

    if (body_value.length == 0) {
        $('#wordCountBody').html(0);
        return;
    }

    if (title_value.length == 0) {
        $('#wordCountTitle').html(0);
        return;
    }

    var regex = /\s+/gi;
    var wordCountBody = body_value.trim().replace(regex, ' ').split(' ').length;
    var wordCountTitle = title_value.trim().replace(regex, ' ').split(' ').length;

    $('#wordCountBody').html(wordCountBody);
    $('#wordCountTitle').html(wordCountTitle);
};

$(document).on('ready page:load', function () {
  $('#count').click(counter);
    $('#post_body, #post_title').on('change keydown keypress keyup blur focus', counter);
});
```

Which doesn't work at all. In fact, whenever I put my cursor in the `#post_title` textfield in my JS console, I get this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
```

Which I suspect is related to the above.

What could be causing this?

Also, I am not sure if the order of these statements in my `post.js` file actually matters, I changed the order for the purposes of this question - so it is more clear.

However, in my actual `post.js`, the order is:

```
var ready;
ready function() declaration
counter function() declaration
$(document).ready(ready);
$(document).on('ready page:load', function () {
  $('#count').click(counter);
    $('#post_body, #post_title').on('change keydown keypress keyup blur focus', counter);
});
```

All of this feels wrong, I just don't know how to combine them and clean this up.

Thoughts?

Comment: Which line of code is the `.length` error on?

Comment: Also, what does this question have to do with rails?  It looks to me like you should remove the rails tags.

Comment: Because this is in a Rails project, and asset-pipeline manages JS files different than a standalone project might. I am also using Turbolinks...which does affect the behavior.

Comment: The line of code that this error is on, is this one in the `counter` function: `if (body_value.length == 0) {`

Comment: Then, it is clear that `body_value` is `undefined` and that happens because `$('#post_body').val()` returns `undefined` and that can happen if `#post_body` doesn't exist or if it isn't a form object that has a `.val()` method.  I think we'd have to see your HTML to advise further.

Comment: Ahh... @jfriend00 you were right. That particular element had an `id=body-field`. So I just changed the variable `body_value` to point to that `ID` and it now works. It is now acting weird in a different way, which I will create a new question for. If you answer the question with that information, I will accept it. Thanks!

Comment: Also @jfriend00 how do I remove the two `document.ready` calls and just consolidate that to one?

Comment: Here is that question, if you think you can help out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28291372/why-does-my-counter-not-work-in-the-field-like-i-would-expect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Then, it is clear that body_value is undefined and that happens because `$('#post_body').val()` returns undefined and that can happen if `#post_body` doesn't exist or if it isn't a form object that has a `.val()` method. I think we'd have to see your HTML to advise further, but it appears that `#post_body` does not exist.