# Why does my counter not work in the field like I would expect

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

I have implemented a JS counter in my app. I have 2 form fields that my two different counters should work for. A `#post_title` and a `#body-field`.

This is my JS:

```js
counter = function() {
 var title_value = $('#post_title').val();  
    var body_value = $('#body-field').val();

    if (title_value.length == 0) {
        $('#wordCountTitle').html(0);
        return;
    }

    if (body_value.length == 0) {
        $('#wordCountBody').html(0);
        return;
    }

    var regex = /\s+/gi;
    var wordCountTitle = title_value.trim().replace(regex, ' ').split(' ').length;
    var wordCountBody = body_value.trim().replace(regex, ' ').split(' ').length;

    $('#wordCountTitle').html(wordCountTitle);
    $('#wordCountBody').html(wordCountBody);
};

$(document).on('ready page:load', function () {
  $('#count').click(counter);
 $('#post_title, #body-field').on('change keydown keypress keyup blur focus', counter);
});
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<label for="title">Title</label>
   <textarea id="post_title" placeholder="Enter Title"></textarea>
   <span id="wordCountTitle">0</span> words<br/>

<label for="report">Report</label>
   <textarea id="body-field"placeholder="Provide all the facts." rows="4">
</textarea><br />
<span id="wordCountBody">0</span> / 150 words
  
</body>

</html>
```

The seemingly stray `$(document).ready(ready);` corresponds to a `var ready = function()` called earlier in the file that I left out for brevity purposes. But I left the `document.ready()` call in the order that it appears just incase it could be causing an issue.

So the issue I am having is, whenever you click on the `#post_title` field and enter words the counter does not update. But as soon as I click on the `#body-field` and start typing not only does the counter for the `#body-field` work and start updating immediately, but the counter for the `#post_title` starts working too and shows the correct amount of words in that field.

What could be causing this?

**Edit 1**

Just playing with that code snippet I realized that the error exists in another state too. If you just add text to the 2nd field first (i.e. the `#body-field`) before entering in the title...the counter for the body-field won't increment. It will only update AFTER you start entering a title in the `#post_title`. So they are both linked somehow.

Comment: I'm sure this is just bad naming, but it's not supposed to be `#post-title`, is it? (you use a hiphen in one, and an underscore in another)

Comment: Can you share the  html as well, a fiddle demo is even better.

Comment: @DanHeberden I wish it were that easy. No, the names are correct. I have added a code snippet so you can see the exact behavior I am talking about. Add some code to the title, then tab to the body and you will see what I mean.

Comment: I updated the question with another error I just discovered that seems to be related to this same issue.

Comment: @Farhan I used a code snippet. Refresh the question to see it. Or did you mean a fiddle outside of that code snippet?

Comment: Initial if blocks returns your function if length is 0, so the code to update counter wont be executed .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not have the `counter` function check and perform operations on both fields. The `counter` function should do exactly the same operation, by utilizing jquery's `this` keyword inside it, or by taking an `event` parameter and using that as an alternative, with `event.target`.

Here's the refactor:

```
var counter = function(event) {
    var fieldValue = $(this).val();
    var wc = fieldValue.trim().replace(regex, ' ').split(' ').length;
    var regex = /\s+/gi;
    var $wcField = $(this)[0] === $('#post_title')[0] ? $('#wordCountTitle') : $('#wordCountBody');

    if (fieldValue.length === 0) {
        $wcField.html('');
        return;
    }

    $wcField.html(wc);
};

$(document).on('ready page:load', function () {
    $('#post_title, #body-field').on('change keyup paste', counter);
});
```

[JSBin playground](http://jsbin.com/doperiwako/1/edit?html,js,output)

Also, I am not entirely sure why you are listening to that many events on those textareas, when `change keyup paste` ought to do it.

Comment: I really like where you are going, but this doesn't work for me. The counter never increments at all. I also don't get an error.

Comment: Oh you're right, because we need to update the wordcount label... Edit forthcoming :)

Comment: If I am not mistaken, will this `$(this)` solution run on every form field?

Comment: Ok almost there with that last edit. The `title` field label doesn't update. I know an easy solution would be to just duplicate the `$wcField` line and use the `#post_title` ID, but that would defeat this whole refactoring exercise now wouldn't it :)

Comment: Done. Take a look again ;)

Comment: One bonus question, say once the values being typed in the field passed the limit, how can I change the color of the font to red to let them know that the limit has passed? E.g. the title should be limited to 7 words or less...once they reach 8 words....the UI should scream at them. Any simple way to do that?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/70091/discussion-between-zealoushacker-and-marcamillion).

Answer (score 1):

the error you're having is because of these 2 blocks of code

```
if (title_value.length == 0) {
    $('#wordCountTitle').html(0);
    return;
}

if (body_value.length == 0) {
    $('#wordCountBody').html(0);
    return;
}
```

This means that in order for the counters to run, both title and body should have some value.  Just remove the `return` on both and it should work.

EDIT

I think removing both if blocks will also give you the same behavior you want.  If you want to have both if blocks, you'll have to separate the counter for the title and body.

EDIT 2

here's a simpler implementation of counter function.

```
counter = function() {
  var title_value = $('#post_title').val();     
  var body_value = $('#body-field').val();

  $('#wordCountTitle').html(title_value.split(' ').length);
  $('#wordCountBody').html(body_value.split(' ').length);
}
```

Comment: So I tried removing the `return` and that does seem to fix that issue, but it creates another one. Once I click in the field, it increments the counter to `1 words` even though I haven't typed anything. In fact, it increments the counters for both title & body fields, once I click in any one of them. FWIW, removing both `if` blocks also gives me this issue.

Comment: this is because of your regex.  `''.replace(/\s+/gi, ' ').split(' ').length` evaluates to 1.  won't a simple `text.split(' ').length` work?

Comment: Nope...just tried it and it doesn't work. I.e. I tried: `var wordCountBody = body_value.trim().text.split(' ').length` and the same for the other variable and it doesn't work.

Comment: `body_value.trim().text.split(' ').length` you have an extra call to `text` there.  You should'v also gotten an error when you tried that.

Comment: this is actually SOOO close. The issue now is the same once I enter a value in 1 field issue it updates the other. In this case, when I enter words in the title field, it increments the counter of the body field from 0 to 1 even though I haven't even clicked in that field. It also does the opposite.

Comment: i now understand why you want to use regex but you should use regex for the split instead of replace.  `'asd  asd'.split(/\s+/).length` (there are 2 spaces in between the asd's)

Comment: Gonna update your answer? Actually..never mind. @zealoushacker got his solution working perfectly. Thanks for the effort though!

Comment: ah i see now.  if you have an empty string, `split` returns an array with the empty string as the only element so you indeed need to have that length check in order to get `0` words.